# why 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() ' happened

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

1.I was trying to implement a data normalization algorithm. The input data "data_train_set" which  is NumPy array

```
data0 = [(x - min(data_train_set))/(max(data_train_set) - min(data_train_set)) for x in data_train_set]
```

2.I do not know where should I put .any or.all

Comment: I think data_train_set could be zero, so it says ambiguous.

Comment: don't calculate `min()` and `max()` in the list comprehention, calculate them outside, is a lot faster for very big arrays, and you calculate `min()` 2 times for each element

Answer (score 2):

any and all take input as an array of booleans or 0's and 1's (numbers greater than zeros) and return True or False.

any returns true if any one value of array is non zero, or true. Else false.

all return true if all values of array are non zero, or true. Else false.

You may use these operators as:

`data0 = any([(x - min(data_train_set))/(max(data_train_set) - min(data_train_set)) for x in data_train_set])`